# TV episode with a man betting on a ship

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

Can you identify this TV episode (probably from the 1950-60 era, possibly Hitchcock)?  Man is on an ocean liner to Europe.  There is a game for the passengers: bet on how far the ship will go in the next 24 hours (noon to noon).  Man overhears a crew member mentioning a storm up ahead.  He bets all he has on a very low mileage.  Later he hears there is no such storm.

He concocts a scheme: he will fall overboard, the ship will have to stop to rescue him, and he will win the bet.  He goes to the fantail where he finds two old ladies sitting.  He chats with them for a little while and then dives off, shouting Hellllp! as he goes.  One of the ladies says, "He seemed like a nice man.  I wonder why he left so suddenly."  They are blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure she was blind? Because this sounds exactly like the *Alfred Hitchcock Presents* episode [Dip in the Pool](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0508106/combined) from 1958, which was an adaptation of [a short story by Roald Dahl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dip_in_the_Pool):

> William Botibol is a compulsive gambler. While on a cruise he enters a betting pool to guess the number of miles the ship will travel in the course of twenty four hours. William gains some inside information when he learns that the ship is going to slow down to avoid an upcoming storm. Unfortunately, the storm passes, and the ship continues to speed on its course. He decides to force the ship to slow down by throwing himself overboard. He figures that when word gets out of someone going overboard the ship will slow down to get him. He picks out a witness and jumps overboard. The witness doesn't say a word. She's mentally ill and does not alert anyone to Williams' plight.

Another woman (possibly her caretaker) arrives and doesn't believe her story, and the witness says, dreamily: "Such a nice man... he waved to me."

Comment: That's the one.  I can't explain where my incorrect memory of the details at the end came from, but, after all, it's been 57 years and I saw it only once.

Comment: @user307178 You were close enough, well done. I know this story well. Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this as 'solved'.